# How can I use custom tokens when grouping Thank You letters

Tags: tokens, receipts

Being able to group Thank You Letters by contact is a great feature for both everyday receipts (we have a company that will donate via multiple smaller donations at once) and end of the year receipts.

But I'm running into a problem, if I use an if statement around a contribution token, the token no longer loops for each contribution printed. For example:

```
{crmAPI var='contresult' entity='Contribution' action='get' sequential=0 id=$note_id}
 {foreach from=$contresult.values item=contribution}
  {if $contribution.non_deductible_amount gt 0}${$contribution.non_deductible_amount}{else}N/A{/if}
 {/foreach}
```

The function doesn't display anything when I 'group by' (If I run a thank you letter for a single contribution it does work.)

In this example:

```
{capture assign='note_id'}{contribution.contribution_id}{/capture}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Note' action='get' sequential=0 entity_table="civicrm_contribution" entity_id=$note_id}
 {assign var='note_count' value=$result.count}
  {if !$note_count}None{elseif $note_count}
   {foreach from=$result.values item=note}{$note.note}{/foreach}
  {/if}
```

It only returns "None" once, when the contributions all have notes.

How can I make the if statement run for each of the contributions selected for the thank you letter?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code, I guess really the HTML, you're using?   That way folks can see the logic, loops, foreach, etc.

Comment: @Paul-Tahoe Done!

Comment: Have you looked at this https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/blob/master/docs/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous.md ?  Near the bottom of the page is some html/smarty's code.  It isn't as complex as yours though it does fill out a table with all the different donations for the period.  Also, it appears that the thank you letter already has an array that most likely includes the non_deductible_amount so you might be able to do like the example and stick you if then in their inner loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `{capture assign='note_id'}{contribution.contribution_id}{/capture}`. When grouping, if you have more than one contribution the output will be ie. `1, 2, 3, 4 ...`, try printing `{$note_id}` when grouping and you'll see what I mean, passing `1, 2, 3, 4` as contribution_id to the API call the response is `"is_error": 1`

**Edit:** so having a look at `CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/PDFLetterCommon.php`, I believe that's the correct class, there´s a `$contributions` variable which holds the contributions, so if you loop through it, the above could look like this:

```
{foreach from=$contributions item=contribution}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Note' action='get' entity_table="civicrm_contribution" entity_id=$contribution.id}
 {assign var='note_count' value=$result.count}
  Contribution note: {if !$note_count}None
  {elseif $note_count}
    {foreach from=$result.values item=note}
      {$note.note}
    {/foreach}
  {/if} 
 | Non deductible amount: {if $contribution.non_deductible_amount gt 0}${$contribution.non_deductible_amount}{else}N/A{/if}
<br/>
{/foreach}
```

Now this **works when grouping** but it won't when you are not grouping, so my guess is that you'll have to create two ThankYou templates, one for grouping and one for ***no grouping***.

Also important to mention this is **smarty** they are not custom tokens.

Comment: My apologies, my original post I referenced both smarty and custom tokens. (I also tried writing a custom token for the note variable but it also failed to show a variable for multiple contributions). I since edited it and added code so I pulled out the mention of custom tokens for an easier read. I printed {$note_id} and it printed out the contribution IDs.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: you are my hero! Totally works didn't realize I could put the foreach around the API.....mind blown!

Comment: Glad it helped!